# Weblogic deployed application calling webservice not working, but in Tomcat deployment works fine

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, weblogic

I am facing problem in calling webservice in my project which is deployed in weblogic, but the same application works fine in tomcat deployment.

```
Error:
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: XXXservices?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Response: '401: Unauthorized' for url: '://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8111/xxx/services?wsdl'.
```

But same works fine in Tomcat deployment.

I search in the net. people said, we need to force weblogic to use sun http handler, so written something like below. but its not works for me.

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler handler = new sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler();
URL wsdlURL = new URL(null, "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8111/xxx/services?wsdl", handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpResponse code 401 denotes that authorization has been refused for the credentials. By default, Weblogic has basic authentication enabled. You can disable it as follows

Setting the enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials Flag
To set the e enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials flag, perform the following steps:
 Add the `<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials`> element to config.xml within the `<security-configuration>` element :

```
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
 false
</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
```

Start or restart all of the servers in the domain. Please go through this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/security/thin_client.html#understanding_basic_atn) for good understanding

Comment: Did you check the enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials value using WLST?

Comment: yes - Please read this documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/using_WLST.html

Comment: thanks for quick reply, actually my boss ask me to do cxf basic authentication instead of http authentication, becoz we are going to deploy in client's weblogic server, we can access that only through web console, so please help me to do cxf basic authentication.

Comment: Sir, you can check out the cxf basic authentication docs, just google.